# Japanese characters are inserting as '?' into oracle db from IE browser

Tags: html, oracle, character-encoding, special-characters

I am getting '?' in oracle db, while inserting the Japanese characters like コメントをご記入ください。 from IE.

Any body having any idea on this ? please help.

Comment: We need more (any ...) information about the architecture of the web application involved ( eg. web server, middleware; db version, nls parameters; db connection settings [in particular locale settings / nls parameters]; db data adoption [sql, stored procedures, file loading]; html forms ). Any piece of software that touches the stream of data starting with IE up to the db engine may play havoc with non-ascii characters. Btw: by which method have you checked that the symbols stored in the db are corrupt ?